# Getting variables by scope

Tags: c++, variables, scope

Is it possible for a function in C++ to find the addresses of all variables in a certain scope? I'm talking about methods such as scanning the memory used by the program, or looking at a compiler's parse tree. Maybe there's even a mechanism added for it in C++11.

This is something I've been wondering about for a few time now, some good answers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

note: the code should be called from inside the program.

Comment: What do you intend to use this for?

Comment: This is more of a general interest question, but one thing I can think of is some sort of a logging function that can be used in loops to track variables.

Comment: I'm going to say no then. There are some helpful ways to do logging, but you can't have access to function variables unless you access them inside the function's scope.

Comment: Variables in C++ don't necessarily become manifest entities in the machine code. Constants may be folded right into the code, and loop counters may be removed if the loop gets unrolled or replaced. Conversely, there may be hidden variables, e.g. for static variable initialization. References may or may note come up at all. The situation is subtle.

Comment: If gdb is able to figure this out, then I guess it's possible. However the question might be how much work that is. I suppose writing some scripts around gdb would be a better idea. It's very scriptable and customizable from what I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that all debuggers can do, so I think it would be possible for a program to get that level of introspection if it is compiled with debug information and can somehow parse its own symbol table.

[This project](http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html) implemented debug info parsing to generate class introspection for C++. I guess the same approach would work for your purposes.

Also, I doubt this will be possible if you compile with optimizations, since the optimizer may change your code enough that a mapping from individual variables in the source code to memory locations does not exist.